# I'm trying to return True if the for loop add to "codelist" the list [0,0,7] but I'm getting True even if I don't have those numbers in my list

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, return

```
def spy_game(nums):
    code = []
    for num in nums:
        if num == 7 and code == [0,0]:
            code.append(7)
        elif num == 0:
            code.append(0)
    return code == [0,0,7]

# Check
spy_game([0,0,0,7]
```

It should get True because it has 0,0,7 in it

Comment: If the size of `code` becomes 2 and the current match fails, you need to reset `code` to `[]`

Comment: But there are three zeroes.

Comment: I don't understand why the third check should be false. there is 0, 0, 7 there too ( the 2nd, 6th,7th numbers)

Comment: @ rdas No, you cannot just reset to empty list.  That will fail on [0, 0, 0, 7]

Comment: You need to clearly enumerate your matching rules.  It isn't obvious that the 2nd one should work and the 3rd should fail.  The 3rd has 0, 0, 7 in it in sequential order, just like the second one, just with intermediate 7's.

Comment: @ChristianSloper thanks, you right I didn't notice. do you know what i should add to get the fourth check too?

Comment: @JeffH thanks, I made a mistake this check is meant to be True and I didn't notice. I edited the info in the question

Comment: Does the [0,0,7] have to be consecutive? Or can they be apart?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep resetting `code` to `[]` when the circumstances are not right and do an immediate return after the check for `[0,0,7]`:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    code = []
    for num in nums:
        if num == 7 and code == [0,0]:
            return True
        elif num == 0:
            if len(code) < 2:
                code.append(0)
        else:
            code = []
    return False

print(spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]))
print(spy_game([7,0,2,4,0,5,7]))
print(spy_game([7,0,7,7,5,0,7]))
print(spy_game([0,0,0,7]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
True
```

Answer (score 1):

More general, if want to look for other spys than just James Bond.

```
def spy_game( nums, target_list):

    for n in nums:
        if not target_list:
            return True
        if n == target_list[0]:
            target_list.pop(0)

    return not target_list

assert spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5],[0,0,7])
assert spy_game([7,0,2,4,0,5,7],[0,0,7])
assert not spy_game([7,0,2,4,0,5,6],[0,0,7])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code here will fail if the case `[0, 0, 0, 7]` is present which I believe should be true.

Now as per the reason why it is returning `true` for the case `spy_game([7,0,7,7,5,0,7])` is that you are not checking whether the zeros which got appended are consecutive. So when you are iterating through the list, first zero gets added then next zero gets added leading to code becoming `[0, 0]`. Then it checks for the seven at the last index. As the code at the point is `[0, 0]` it appends seven and voila!! The value of code is `[0, 0, 7]` before returning.

The best way would be to start iterating from the second position and check the previous two values.

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for index in range(2, len(nums)):
        if nums[index-2] == 0 and nums[index-1] == 0 and nums[index] == 7:
            return true
    return false
```

What happens in this case is that it checks the whether the current value is seven and the previous two are zeros. If YES then it returns true. If it doesn't find any such conditions then at the end it returns false.

Hope that helps!